# Make ul list items behave the same to that of a table near it

Tags: html, css, list, html-table

I have list and a table next to each other, and I want to make the the list elements to be the same height as of that of the table cells with only CSS. Here is my example:

HTML

```
<div class="main_holder">
    <div class="list_table_holder">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div>
                    List cell 1
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>
                    List cell 2
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div>
                    List cell 3
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="table_holder">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, c</p>
                            <img src="" alt="Some image" width="200" height="200" />
                            <strong>Some bold text</strong>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, c</p>
                            <img src="" alt="Some image" width="200" height="200" />
                            <strong>Some bold text</strong>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, c</p>
                            <img src="" alt="Some image" width="200" height="200" />
                            <strong>Some bold text</strong>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commo
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmo
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main_holder {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.list_table_holder {
    width: 210px;
}

.list_table_holder ul {
    display: table;
}

.list_table_holder li {
    display: table-row;
}

.list_table_holder div {
    display: table-cell;
}

.table_holder {
    width: calc(100% - 230px);
}

td {
  vertical-align: top;  
}

strong {
    display: block;
}
```

Here is jsfiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/wvtze60z/

As I said if possible I would like to resolve this without the use of Javascript/jQuery.

Comment: This won't be possible with CSS alone if the contents of the cells have variable heights. You would need to use JavaScript.

Comment: Why are you not able to implement the list in the table? That would make your site structure easier to understand (and so to help).

Comment: @MarianRick the purpose behind is cause the table will be animated. It will move left and right using translate.

Comment: @solenoo I have updated my answer and added a pure css solution, which helps to fix a column and achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You asked, if possible, if this could be done without JavaScript and the answer is, unfortunately not. Given that the table cells will have variable heights and that they have no direct relationship with the list items, there's no way of doing it with CSS alone.

To give you a simple JavaScript solution, you'd need to load the table rows and list items into collections and then loop through the rows, using their `offsetHeight` to set the `height` property of the items.

Note that the below assumes that there is only one list and one table in your HTML. If this is not the case, then you'll need to give IDs to the relevant list and table and adjust this JS accordingly.

```
var rows=document.getElementsByTagName("tr"),items=document.getElementsByTagName("li"),x=rows.length;
while(x--)
    items[x].style.height=parseInt(rows[x].offsetHeight)+"px";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a clean css solution you will have to integrate the list into your table. As described in your comment you want the first column of the table to be fixed. You can achieve this with something like this:

```
<div id="table-wrapper">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="fixed"> Title </td>
    <td> Some Content </td>
    <td> Some Content </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Then you need to fix the first `td.fixed` element with some css:

```
<style>
.fixed {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100px;
   top: auto;
   left: 0;
}
#table-wrapper {
   width: 200px;
   margin-left: 100px; /* As defined as with for .fixed */
    overflow-x:scroll;  
    overflow-y:visible;
}
</style>
```

You can find [**your working jsFiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/wvtze60z/2/).

**Alternativ**

If you are willing to use jQuery, you could assign an `id` to every `tr` and get their height with something like:

```
$('#tr1').height();
$('#tr2').height();
```

and assign these to your table.

If you need further explanation please let me know! Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this is a conveniente behavior, because you dont want to deal with conditionals for printing a tr or a td, or somethimes you are in frameworks like Angular and this is not a choice using something like `*ngIf`. Therefore, my idea is to create a responsive layout by dividing the width of the items in the percentages, based on the amount of columns you want, e.g. if you want 2 columns then the amount of with per item is about a 50%:

Lets see this in Sass/Scss code

```css
ul.layout {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;

  li {
    margin-right: 0.8em;
    margin-bottom: 0.8em;
    width: calc(50% - 0.8em);
    display: block;

    &.double {
      width: calc(100% - 0.8em);
    }
  }

  &.triple {
    li {
      width: calc(33% - 0.8em);

      &.double {
        width: calc(66% - 0.8em);
      }

      &.triple {
        width: calc(100% - 0.8em);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the HTML is self-explanatory

```html
  <ul class="layout">
    <li>
      <span class="item">Content A</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="item">Content B</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="item">Content C</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="item">Content D</span>
    </li>
    <li class="double">
      <span class="item">Content E</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

You can even adapt the CSS to support triple columns by just adding the class `triple`.
This might be improved for sure, but I think that you get the idea.